# Handling directories with spaces Python subprocess.call()

Tags: python, subprocess, directory

I'm trying to create a program that scans a text file and passes arguments to subprocess. Everything works fine until I get directories with spaces in the path.

My split method, which breaks down the arguments trips up over the spaces:

```
s = "svn move folder/hello\ world anotherfolder/hello\ world"

task = s.split(" ")
process = subprocess.check_call(task, shell = False)
```

Do, either I need function to parse the correct arguments, or I pass the whole string to the subprocess without breaking it down first.

I'm a little lost though.

Comment: Can you rely on a fixed number of space-delimited left tokens?

Comment: how about quoting file names?

Comment: if you create the filename that is being read, why not have the values comma seperated? and then split on "," instead of all the hassle?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a list instead:

```
task = ["svn",  "move",  "folder/hello world", "anotherfolder/hello world"]
subprocess.check_call(task)
```

If your file contains whole commands, not just paths then you could try [shlex.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex):

```
task = shlex.split(s)
subprocess.check_call(task)
```

Comment: thank you thank you! using a list solves all sorts of weird quoting/escaping issues +1