# open file with spaces in path

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to open a file with spaces in path with subprocess.call function but I can't get it working.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['cmd','/c','start C:/Users/akg/Desktop/file 1.png'])
```

I've tried also

```
import subprocess
file= '"C:/Users/akg/Desktop/file 1.png"'
subprocess.call(['cmd','/c','start '+file])
```

But I still getting this error 
1st case :
[image: 1st case screenshot], 2nd case [image: 2nd case : screenshot]
even spliting the command whenever there is a whitespace is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling directories with spaces Python subprocess.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846232/handling-directories-with-spaces-python-subprocess-call)

Comment: It's a little bit different. it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is to delete the start option as described here : [Opening file with spaces in Windows via Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691827/opening-file-with-spaces-in-windows-via-command-prompt)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['cmd','/c',"C:/Users/akg/Desktop/file 1.png"])
```

or

```
subprocess.call(['cmd', '/c', 'start', "", "C:/Users/akg/Desktop/file 1.png"])
```

Thank you all

Comment: with a small change it works `subprocess.call(['cmd', '/c', 'start', "", "C:/Users/akg/Desktop/file 1.png"])`

Answer (score 1):

You should put every argument as a separate item in the list passed to `subprocess.call`:

```
subprocess.call(['cmd','/c','start', 'C:/Users/akg/Desktop/file 1.png'])
```

Comment: @PeterWood True. Updated as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: See also [**`list2cmdline`**](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L486)

Comment: When i split the command the cmd opens without doing anything. Thanks for the reply